# Angular 2 ERROR in ./~/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js

Tags: angular

I execute the command ng serve and an error occurs

> (ERROR in ./~/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js Module not found:
>   Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common/http' in
>   'D:\study_project\bookstore-angular\admin-portal\node_modules\@angular\material\esm5')

My package.json wrote below

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/cdk": "github:angular/cdk-builds",
    "@angular/common": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/core": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/http": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/material": "github:angular/material2-builds",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.4.10",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.4.0",
    "@angular/router": "^3.4.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.4.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~3.2.0",
    "karma": "~1.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^0.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~2.0.0",
    "tslint": "~4.4.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you `npm install`?

Comment: Try running npm update

Comment: The http package referenced in your error '@angular/common/http' has been added in angular 4.3. If you are using a pre 4.3 version you should use '@angular/http' and vice versa

Comment: Explosion Pills Yes

Comment: Andreas W I use import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';

Comment: @Tim which Angular version are you using?

Comment: @Tim Did you solve the issue?

Answer (score 2):

Just run commands npm update and npm install and restart your editor or app