# ./node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/table.es5.js Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/common' in '../../\node_modules\@angular\cdk\esm5'

Tags: angular, angular-material-7

after the installation of angular material, and angular animations. I got this error. I reinstall the angular/cdk  infact still am having this error and dont know how to solve this issue.

Comment: See: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761557/angular-2-error-in-angular-material-esm5-icon-es5-js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761557/angular-2-error-in-angular-material-esm5-icon-es5-js)

Comment: Also: [https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/973](https://github.com/gdi2290/angular-starter/issues/973)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 ERROR in ./~/@angular/material/esm5/icon.es5.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47761557/angular-2-error-in-angular-material-esm5-icon-es5-js)